# What is the purpose of this voltage divider (R16 & R19) in the RC snubber circuit?

Tags: voltage-divider, snubber

[image]

What is the voltage divider used for in this circuit?

Comment: I would guess to discharge the capacitor when the circuit is not plugged in.

Comment: @Damien if I want to connect 6 LEDs in strip does it need to change values of this resistors? Total voltage is near 10 Volts. and 3 Volts at the middle of the voltage divider. Does it neccessary to provide same voltage near 3 Volts there?

Comment: Changing R16 & R19 won't affect the current of the LEDs (in any significant way), so no you don't need. Although this circuit feels a bit strange, feels like an inductor is missing, where did you get it ?

Comment: You don't show where the point in the middle of the divider is connected to, and this connection is probably the purpose of the divider.

Comment: @AlexVB That's feedback pin. There up to 3V. And the purpose as Damien said for discharge the capacitor i think.

Comment: @Damien Not sure that I can publish it. Maybe it's private information.

Comment: As of it, it seems this circuit would probably destroy the LEDs, I don't see what would limit the current on the LEDs.

Comment: @Damien The Vddled is probably tuned so that current through the LEDs is not higher than they can consume.

Comment: LED doesn't limit current @AlexVB, you can't tune a Voltage to adjust current in an LED.

Comment: @Damien IV-curve for a LED has some slope so the current is limited in the sense it is not infinite. The current at specific voltage may vary for each diode, but it is in certain limits. http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/

Comment: The temperature dependency is way too high to control the LEDs this way @AlexVB

Comment: An inductor is probably missing on this schematic, it may be the line that goes done from the node, but who knows. Also the note "keep the trace short" imply an inductor should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage divider for feedback likely, which is connected between R16 and R19 (not shown below pic).

If it's for capacitor discharge, the design could've just placed a 100k across  the caps.

Comment: If that was the case, it probably wouldn't be connected to the mosfet source.

Comment: @Damien You're right. if black net is REFGND, it would be weird to have a feedback close to zero, unless the black net is connected to a current limiting resistor in the return path.